Maui Community Toolkit MediaElement crashing
I am having problems with the Maui Community Toolkit MediaElement. To boil down the problem, I have created a brand new Maui App template, followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement and only added:
<toolkit:MediaElement HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400" Source="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videosbucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True" />

I keep getting this error/exception in the console:
MediaManager: Error: AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager.Content.LocalBroadcastManager not supported on Android 13 and above.

The problem, however, gets worse in my real app. After implementing the IPopupService from the Toolkit the Mediaelement crashes the app:
Information: 0 : MediaControlsService destroyed.
The program 'xxxxx.MAUI.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Any ideas why this happens? Any ideas how this can be handled?

Since you mentioned popup, are you waiting for the media to stop before closing the popup?

The media is not in the popup but in the "main" page below the popup.

As a maintainer on the toolkit it would be really helpful if you could raise this bug on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui along with any extra details like which version of Android you are using, etc.

Yeah. If I am the only one experiencing this I guess it must be my setup it is just hugely frustrating being stuck in my project...

Is fixed by the Community Toolkit crew:
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/2143
